# Task executor not stopping

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, spring-integration, threadpoolexecutor

In my code: spring-integration, a scatter gather channel is there and the scatter channel using a task-executor to call two micro-services parallely and gather the response in gather channel. I used logger channel to log request response in the scatter gather channel. I can see the response from two services came to gather channel but stuck there not going to next channel. I suspected release strategy of gather channel may not working but same is working if I don't use thread(task executor). Suggest something. Thanks.

Comment: Would be great to have some simple code to play from our side. Sounds like not related to the Scatter-Gather, but you somehow lose correlation headers during scatter phase.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have in between some persistent message store, so `replyChannel` header is removed during message serialization.

I suggest you to use `<header-enricher>` with the `header-channels-to-string` option to convert the `replyChannel` to string representation.

Meanwhile you're free to raise a JIRA about this issue in the Scatter-Gather. And we can make that string conversion as out-of-the-box feature, like it is right now there for the `gatherResultChannel`:

```
PollableChannel gatherResultChannel = new QueueChannel();

Object gatherResultChannelName = this.replyChannelRegistry.channelToChannelName(gatherResultChannel);

Message<?> scatterMessage = getMessageBuilderFactory()
            .fromMessage(requestMessage)
            .setHeader(GATHER_RESULT_CHANNEL, gatherResultChannelName)
            .setReplyChannel(this.gatherChannel)
            .build();
```